# C# LINQ query a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a C# dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, ItemsClass> Items
```

`ItemsClass` has a member called `Number`

I want to write a LINQ query that returns me the Dictionary key number for the `ItemsClass` that has a `Number` matching a certain value e.g. x.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

To get all matching items you would use:

```
Items.Where(p => p.Value.Number == x).Select(p => p.Key);
```

To get the only key it you always expect it to find one, and only one:

```
Items.Where(p => p.Value.Number == x).Select(p => p.Key).Single();
```

To get the first matching item, if there are multiple items:

```
Items.Where(p => p.Value.Number == x).Select(p => p.Key).First();
```

Comment: Minor correction: From my reading it would be `p.Value.Number == x`. Also may also be worth using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` since the implication is that there is only a single result expected rather than multiple possible.

Comment: Ensure you have System.Linq using statement included at the top.