# Sorting a Data file into the categories given to them

Tags: c#, json, sorting

I am currently in the process of setting up a plugin for a game server i host and i have a whole bunch of items that have a "category" between 1 & 11 as shown in a small snippet below. I only ask this because there are over 200 items i will need to sort into different categories.

```
    "ammo.rifle.hv_0": {
      "shortname": "ammo.rifle.hv",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 64,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 9,
      "displayName": "HV 5.56 Rifle Ammo",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    },
    "radiationresisttea.pure_0": {
      "shortname": "radiationresisttea.pure",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 1,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 8,
      "displayName": "Pure Anti-Rad Tea",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    },
    "healingtea.pure_0": {
      "shortname": "healingtea.pure",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 1,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 8,
      "displayName": "Pure Healing Tea",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    },
    "ammo.rifle_0": {
      "shortname": "ammo.rifle",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 64,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 9,
      "displayName": "5.56 Rifle Ammo",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    },
    "blueberries_0": {
      "shortname": "blueberries",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 1,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 8,
      "displayName": "Blueberries",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    }
}
```

From this is there a way to index them in a way it will select all the ones with a certain "category".

For example, If i want all the ones with `"category": 9` it will display the following

```
    "ammo.rifle_0": {
      "shortname": "ammo.rifle",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 64,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 9,
      "displayName": "5.56 Rifle Ammo",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    },
    "ammo.rifle.hv_0": {
      "shortname": "ammo.rifle.hv",
      "customIcon": null,
      "amount": 64,
      "skinId": 0,
      "isBp": false,
      "category": 9,
      "displayName": "HV 5.56 Rifle Ammo",
      "cost": 10000,
      "cooldown": 0
    }
```

Please and thank you in advanced

Comment: you want to sort this with C# or Javascript?

Comment: What have you written in C# so far?

Comment: Create a class whose properties match the properties of each item (i.e., `shortname`..`cooldown`). Then deserialize the JSON into a `Dictionary<string, YourClass>`. That will get you halfway there.

Comment: Is that data going to be deserialized in your C# code? Or are you looking to read the json file and look for the objects with the specified category?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this approach:

**Define the corresponding class that matches your objects:**

```
public class SomeObject{
  public string ShortName {get; set;}
  /// ... add all other properties.
}
```

---

**Convert your incoming data from json to c# objects:**

Here you could choose to use Newtonsoft package. But there's many other libraries available to help you out on this. But here's what you could do using Newtonsoft

```
var myData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,SomeObject> >(jsonString);
```

This will create a new `Dictionary<string, SomeObject>` based on the data provided.

---

**You can query the data in `myData` using LINQ i.e Let's get the items where `category == 9`**

```
result = myData.Where(p => p.Category == 9).ToDictionary<string,SomeObject>();
```

This will get a new dictionary as `result` with `keys` whose `SomeObject.caterory` equals to `9`.

---

Some references that will help you include:

1. [Convert JSON to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)
2. [Query Dictionary using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703184/c-sharp-linq-query-a-dictionary)